# How to pass data from Rabbitmq handler to websocket client

Tags: go, websocket, rabbitmq

I have two anonymous go routines first go routine serves as a handler for the WebSocket connection. The second one is used to create Rabbit service, register consumers, and consume messages from the Rabittmq que

What I want is to achieve once the message is received from the queue to send it to the WebSocket connection.

Problem is that passing reference from one go routine to another block routine for incoming connections

Main

`    package main

```
import (
"fmt"
"github.com/google/uuid"
"github.com/gorilla/websocket"
"log"
grpcclient "nbozic/websockets/grpc-client"
"nbozic/websockets/model"
as "nbozic/websockets/proto-gen/proto"
"nbozic/websockets/service"
"net/http"
"os"
"strings"
"sync"
)
```

const (
readBufferSize  = 1024
writeBufferSize = 1024
)

```
var upgrades = websocket.Upgrader{
ReadBufferSize:  readBufferSize,
WriteBufferSize: writeBufferSize,
CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
    return true
},
}

func getJWT(r *http.Request) string {
authValue := r.Header.Get("Authorization")
return strings.Fields(authValue)[1]
}

func main() {
loadEnvVariables()

wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
wg.Add(2)

userIdChan := make(chan string)

go func() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        conn, err := upgrades.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            _, err := w.Write([]byte("failed upgrading connection"))
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
            return
        }

        defer conn.Close()

        clientService := service.NewClientService(conn) // want to get this reference in the rabbitmq handler so i can send message

        done := make(chan struct{})
        clientID := uuid.New().String()

        if _, exists := r.Header["Authorization"]; exists {
            jwt := getJWT(r)
            grpc, err := grpcclient.GetGrpcClient(os.Getenv("AS"))
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("did not connect: %s", err)
            }
            defer grpc.Close()

            sessionClient := as.NewSessionServiceClient(grpc)
            authService := service.NewAuthService(sessionClient)
            res, err := authService.ValidateSession(jwt)
            if err != nil {
                clientService.Send(fmt.Sprintf("Internal server error"))
            }

            clientService.Send(fmt.Sprintf("Server: Welcome! Your ID is %s,      userIdChan is %v ", clientID, res.User.Id))
            clientService.SaveConnection(res.User.Id, clientID)

            go clientService.WritePump(res.User.Id, done)
            clientService.ReadPump(res.User.Id, done)
            //clientService.ReadPumCh(res.User.Id, userIdChan, done)

        }
        clientService.Send(fmt.Sprintf("Authentication error"))
    })

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":3071", nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    wg.Done()
}()

go func() {
    rabbitService := service.NewRabbitService(&service.RabbitConfig{
        Schema:         model.SCHEMA,
        Username:       os.Getenv("RMQ_USERNAME"),
        Password:       os.Getenv("RMQ_PASSWORD"),
        Host:           os.Getenv("RMQ_HOST"),
        Port:           os.Getenv("RMQ_PORT"),
        VHost:          os.Getenv("RMQ_VHOST"),
        ConnectionName: model.CONNECTION_NAME,
        ExchangeName:   model.EXCHANGE_NAME,
        ExchangeType:   model.EXCHANGE_TOPIC,
    })
    if err := rabbitService.Connect(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("unable to connect to rabbit", err)
    }
    testHandler := service.NewTestHandler(&service.TestHandlerConfig{RabbitService: rabbitService, ExchangeConfig: &service.ExchangeConfig{
        RoutingKey:   model.TEST_HANDLER_EVENT,
        QueueName:    model.QUE_NAME,
        ConsumerName: model.TEST_HANDLER_NAME,
    }})
    testHandler.Declare()
    // want to pass client servisce to this function
    testHandler.Handle(userIdChan)
    wg.Done()
}()

wg.Wait()
}
```

`

I tried to pass message from HandlerService to ClientServie in order to pass data from the que to websocket connection